# Rails - Difficulty figuring out relationships/associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationships

I am having some difficulty figuring out the proper relationships for my database.

I have a Course, AssignmentType, and Assignment model. 
AssignmentType is essentially a label that can be placed to each of the assignments to categorize them (there is a "weight value" that corresponds to each AssignmentType).

The following are some relationships I think could work, but I am not sure which would be the better approach:

Course has many AssignmentTypes, AssignmentType has many Assignments & belongs to course, Assignment belongs to AssignmentType

Course has many Assignments through AssignmentTypes

Course has many Assignments. AssignmentType has many assignments. Assignment belongs to course, Assignment belongs to Assignment Type

Course has many Assignments. Assignment has one Assignment type.

I am really confused as to which would be the proper relationship set to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends on what your needs are. To me, for example, it seems like a Course has many Assignments, Assignments belongs_to AssignmentType and Course. AssignmentType has_many Assignments. Course has_many AssignmentTypes through Assignments.

Comment: I was halfway through writing exactly what Leo said ^.

Comment: Ah, that seems like a reasonable relationship set. I will give it a try and let you know how it works. Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you need to answer (for yourself and anyone you'd like to help you) what the basic cardinality relationships are.  For instance, can any one Assignment have multiple AssignmentType's associated with it?

Comment: Ok so an AssignmentType is used to categorize the assignments. An attribute of assignment type is a "weight" which is used to calculate the influence of an assignment on gpa. So a course has many assignments and assignment types. Each assignment will only have one assignment type associated with it. But an assignment must belong to an assignment type.

Comment: Actually, I just realized there would be a problem with that setup. I need it so that an AssignmentType can exist without an assignment. Would it work if I had Course has many AssignmentTypes, AssignmentType has many Assignments, Course has_many Assignments through AssignmentType